# Counting and categorising instances of certain fields

Tags: cakephp

I'm currently writing a survey style app that has some models:

- Assessments
- Recommendations

An assessment has many recommendations and is joined by the assessments_recommendations table, and I store data in the join table which are effectively answers.

One such answer is user impact. This field is an integer value between 0 and 10 and is different for each assessment->recommendation.

What I want to be able to do is send a count and categorisation of that field into a view so that I can chart it using chart.js. For example, I would like:

- 0-3 = Low
- 4-7 = Moderate
- 8-10 = High

As far as I can tell, I need to pass something along the lines of:

$counts [4, 6, 8]
$legend ['Low', 'Moderate', 'High']

So in the above example, 4 assessment->recommendations are classed as low, 6 are moderate, 8 are high.

Does anyone have any advice on how to do this in my controller? I've been reading up on collections but I'm not sure that is the correct way of doing this. I had issues as my data is stored in the _joinData part of the array and I couldn't figure out how to access it.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

**Edit 1**

This is the controller code I have been playing around with to get an initial collection working. The col variable passes through nicely and I can see this in the view. I get 'unknown getter' error on the join data line though. It isn't entirely clear to me from the docs what variables are what in the example in the book, so I've been very much trying every combo I can think of to try and get it to work before even trying to move on with the complete scenario.

```
public function view($id = null)
{
    $this->loadModel ('Assessments');
    $this->loadModel ('Recommendations');

    $query = $this->Assessments->find('all', [
        'conditions' => ['Assessments.id =' => $id],
        'contain' => ['Recommendations']
    ]);
    $assessment = $query->first();  

    $collection = new Collection($assessment->ToArray());

    $countHigh = $collection->countBy(function ($assessment) {
        return $assessment->_joinData->_user_impact > 7 ? 'High' : 'Error';
    });


    $this->set('assessments', $assessment);
    $this->set('col', $collection);
    $this->set('user_impact_high', $countHigh);
}
```

**Edit 2**

So I'm testing this some more. Trying to simplify it. Even using the groupBy function in it's simple form is failing. The code below generates the following error.

```
public function view($id = null)
{
    $this->loadModel ('Assessments');
    $this->loadModel ('Recommendations');

    $query = $this->Assessments->find('all', [
        'conditions' => ['Assessments.id =' => $id],
        'contain' => ['Recommendations']
    ]);
    $assessment = $query->first();  

    $collection = new Collection($assessment->ToArray());

    $test = $collection->groupBy('client_id');

    $this->set('assessments', $assessment);
    $this->set('col', $collection);
    $this->set('test', $test);
}
```

Error:

> Cannot use object of type Cake\I18n\FrozenTime as array

Comment: A collection is certainly one way to go about it. Show what you've tried, and an example of the data you're passing into the collection, and we'll help from there. (Hint, [countBy](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake\Collection\Collection::countBy) is probably the function you want to use.)

Comment: I've added the initial code I've been playing with. Trying to follow the examples in the book but I'm struggling to grasp the concept (as you can probably tell from my code above!).

Comment: You're setting `$assessment` to a single entity, which you then convert into array form. That's not what you want. Try eliminating that, and use `$collection = new Collection($query);` or at worst `$collection = new Collection($query->all());`.

Comment: Whenever you get errors like this, which indicate that your data is not what you expect it to be, your first step should always be to output the variable in question to see how it differs from what you're expecting. In this case, it'll show you that you've got individual values there instead of entities, which should point you in the right direction.